# pm uninstall -k --user 0 Failure [DELETE_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]

Tags: android, shell, package, adb, uninstallation

I have been following the instructions from https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-system-app-bloatware-android/ to remove bloatware (that actually kills FCM and blocks notifications.

However I encountered Failure [DELETE_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]. I have checked the current user is 0 by am get-current-user, and as far as i understand it is the root user.
So why is the uninstallation failed? Any logs or further troubleshooting tips? Thanks very much as this is causing the phone not functioning properly.

```
PD2170:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.iqoo.powersaving
Success
PD2170:/ $ pm list packages | grep pem
package:com.vivo.pem
PD2170:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.vivo.pem
Success
PD2170:/ $ pm list packages | grep abe
package:com.vivo.abe
PD2170:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.vivo.abe
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED]
```

Answer (score 6):

If the regular adb disable/uninstall commands do not work then-

For Android 13 try:

```
adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.abc.xyz i32 0 i32 0
```

For Android 12 try:

```
adb shell service call package 134 s16 com.abc.xyz i32 0 i32 0
```

Explanation: This is calling the function at line:134 (see more below) and passing three arguments to the function:
com.abc.xyz (datatype: s16)
0 (datatype: i32)
0 (datatype: i32)

PS: This is tested on vivo/iqoo phones. For other brands the command number (131/134) for the uninstall function depends on decoding & decompiling the framework.jar file in /system/framework/framework.jar

PPS: Also com.vivo.abe & com.vivo.pushservice will not uninstall using this method, however the rest of the system bloatware can be removed.

Source: https://dtf.ru/u/523140-danila-romanov/1154461-eshche-odin-sposob-udaleniya-predustanovlennyh-prilozheniy-android-12

Comment: Thanks for the very updated answer. I have this attempted on my new vivo Fold 2
and the parcel return is 
"Only system callers can mod ify core apps"
"Package Manager Service"
"setSys temApp In stall StallState Pack age(Package Ma nager Service)"
"Binder Server"
"PackageManagerService transact"
"External (Binder)"
"Transaction too large"
"Failed to bind to"
I guess it mean unsuccessful, sadly

Comment: After decoding the above trash. I think have called the correct function  "setSystemAppInstallState". They have also barred this method (as of May 3)

Comment: Can we restore any apps deleted this way ?

Answer (score 1):

Some apps can only be removed by root on a rooted device.
You can try disabling instead of uninstalling the app for similar results:

```
pm disable-user --user 0 com.vivo.abe
```

You can find a full guide here: https://www.xda-developers.com/disable-system-app-bloatware-android/

Comment: Thanks for an instant reply. The new error thrown is it requires root permission.

Comment: Exception occurred while executing 'disable-user':
java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot disable com.vivo.abe no root permission

Comment: I have to assume that the app cannot be removed or disabled without rooting then. This is very unfortunate. You can at least freeze the app and block it from running in the background by using `cmd appops set <package_name> RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore`. This is taken from this guide: https://technastic.com/vivo-bloatware-preinstalled-apps-list/

Comment: Thanks for the good reference. I have freeze the app and will see if the notification will improve. Since I have confirmed from the debug log the FCM is still active, the only problem that blocks notification arriving is the power management by vivo.